# adobe air command line parameters

Tags: air

I am using parameters from the command line which come in through the invoke handler of my WindowedApplication. I used to build using the excellent Flash Develop, we are now using Flash Builder 4.

I would like to know where do I enter these parameters in Flash Builder 4 so I can test them while debugging my app.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in FlashDevelop3? I tried a few things of which I thought it could be, but sadly they are not. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);   

function onInvoke(e:InvokeEvent):void   
{  
    trace('onInvoke', e.arguments);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering this question for Spark Application container. The WindowedApplication class allows you to do:

```
<s:WindowedApplication
    invoke="onInvoke()"
>
```

but the Application container does not, so instead, you need to do this:

```
<s:Application
    ...
    preinitialize="onPreinitialize()"
>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function onPreinitialize():void
        {
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);
        }

        private function onInvoke(e:InvokeEvent):void
        {
             // e.arguments is an array containing the command line args
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```